# Externalize vuejs configuration on statically hosted application

Tags: webpack, configuration, vuejs2, frontend

I run a VueJs application hosted via static resources of a springboot application.

So far I deal with external configuration successfully the following way.

I create static `externalConf.js` that I read at runtime if `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`

`public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <script src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/externalizedConf.js"></script>
</head>
```

`public/js/externalizedConf.js`

```
config = {
    VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL : "http://virwse03dev.devagipi.local:8094/api"
}
```

In some js file reading the configuration :

```
const frontApiUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'?window.config.VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL:process.env.VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL
```

This is working fine but is there a more standard way to inject configuration into packaged vuejs frontend application? It seems a bit of a hack to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way to have some configurations based on the environment is to build bundles for different environments that have their own configs, using `Webpack DefinePlugin`.

in your example you have the following Webpack config:

```
{
   ...
   plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         isProd: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
   ],
   ...
}
```

and simply your `public/js/externalizedConf.js` would be:

```
export default {
   FRONT_API_URL: isProd ? 'https://production.api' : 'http://dev.api',
}
```

You can read more about [Webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin).

Also, Vue CLI 3 introduces new way to [define and use environment variables through the Vue app](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case, but spring-cloud-config has a nice feature for this. See [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html). Also [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__embedding_the_config_server.html) kind of config should be helpful for you.

**edit:**

Maybe simpler solution would be this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTemplateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTemplateApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver javascriptViewResolver() {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
            resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.js"});
            return resolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            engine.addTemplateResolver(javascriptTemplateResolver());
            return engine;
        }

        public ITemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            resolver.setOrder(1);
            resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
            resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/js/");
            resolver.setCacheable(false);
            resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
            return resolver;
        }
    }


    @Controller
    public static class JavascriptController {

        @Value("${VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL:NOTDEFINED!!!}")
        private String vueApiUrl;

        @GetMapping(value = "/js/{file}", produces = "text/javascript")
        public String getJavascript(@PathVariable("file") final String file, final Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL", vueApiUrl);
            return file;
        }
    }

}
```

and in your `resources/static/js` put file `externalizedConf.js` with content

```
config = {
    VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL : [(${VUE_APP_FRONT_API_URL})]
}
```

and `pom.xml` for dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-template</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-template</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when you access url `http://host:port/js/externalizedConf.js` you should get content with replaced placeholder. And of course you can use spring's [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to config different property value for different environment/profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We don't use Spring for this but a servlet and some templating utility class from the backend. 

Actually my question was more about the frontend side best practices.

When we deploy it the javascript application is already bundled and I wonder if there is a way to alter configuration with some kind of environment variable.maybe with something like this : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: What you mean by environment variables? It's possible to get all environments (server side) variables available for spring on some endpoint. I'm not front-end developer so I can help you only the backend side.

Comment: Yes, I may have not expressed myself clearly. I am looking for frontend best practices actually. However, your answer also helped me because it is more parametrable than my current backend implementation. I thank you for that.